# How do I take an hourly sum of one field value in splunk

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

```
2020-12-07 23:57:10,160 INFO  [+] Number of fetched Availability to publish to Gcp PubSub topic. [ClassUnitKey=BU-STO-460] [NumberOfMessages=95] , [bsName="BsRunBatch"], [userId="S-OLB-U-ITSEELM"], [userIdRegion="EU"]
```

As the above splunk log message , How to find the sum of [NumberOfMessages=95] field value in a hourly basis. I have written as below

|  timechart span=1h sum(NumberofMessages)

Its not giving the desired result. The below result i got
[image]

[image]

Comment: Is that the complete query?  If not then please share the full search string.  What result do you get?  Is the NumerOfMessages field extracted?

Comment: @RichG i have added the full search string and result. Please have a look.

Comment: Did you notice the red error indicator and the "Connection refused" error message?  That should be investigated and resolved.  The time range of the search is odd - the screen shot shows the start time is after the end time.  What results does the Statistics tab show?

Comment: Please see question ,latest search results screen shot added. Above you mentioned two mistakes corrected but still result is same.

Comment: The error is gone, that's good, but the start time is still after the end time.  It would help to see the Statistics tab.  I suspect the results you get are not numeric so they can't be graphed.

Comment: Is the field "`NumberOf Messages`" being extracted?

Comment: No, The field "NumberOf Messages" notextracted

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
| bin _time span=1h | stats sum(NumberofMessages) by _time
```

timechart can overwrite your span depending on your time window